# How to implement ViewCacheExtension with RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I can't find any examples or scenarios where to use ViewCacheExtension. The documentation says :

> When getViewForPosition(int) is called, Recycler checks attached scrap
>   and first level cache to find a matching View. If it cannot find a
>   suitable View, Recycler will call the
>   getViewForPositionAndType(Recycler, int, int) before checking
>   RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool

I have few related queries :

1. I understand the attached scrap is a list of views which need not be rebound. But what is the "first level cache" ?
2. The [getViewForPositionAndType()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewCacheExtension.html#getViewForPositionAndType(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Recycler,%20int,%20int)) method documentation says :

> This method should not create a new View

How else can I return a view ? The only way I can think of is by caching scrapped views in the ViewCacheExtension. And when ViewCacheExtension is full, then try moving data to RecycledViewPool. Can someone confirm if I am right ? What's the point in having 4 levels of cache (scrap, "first level", ViewCacheExtension, RecycledViewPool) ?

Even after looking at the RecyclerView source code, I could not find references of ViewCacheExtensions being implemented.

Comment: you can find demo from this article:
https://android.jlelse.eu/anatomy-of-recyclerview-part-1-a-search-for-a-viewholder-continued-d81c631a2b91 ViewCacheExtension may used to save special view, so we may not need to implement this.

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar problem as i needed to cache the recycler view items(i was inflating the view used in recyclerview and size was variable... hence each time there was a view inflation and sudden jerk )

recycler view caching is already provided and i guess recycler view does that just cache size is set to zero

so when i added this line caching was successful and the jerk was only for first time

```
mRecyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(data.getCount());
```

But also i have confusion in case if the user wants to cache only specific views. Kindly post if you get something

hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks. I also took a similar approach, but I am not sure of the side effects on memory if data.getCount() is large.

Comment: The default `ItemViewCacheSize` is 2 in RecyclerView. This is used to keep items when user scrolls. If you make it equal to the size of your data, then RecyclerView won't be able to do its job. I will not recycle anything. You will lose most performance gains.